# WordPress 4.6 to 4.7 having issue upgrading on Azure

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, wordpress-4.7, wordpress-4.6

I am trying to upgrade my WordPress website from version 4.6 to 4.7. When I try this through the WordPress panel, I get an error after about 3 minutes of waiting which is:

> 500 - The request timed out.
>
> The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

I have tried the upgrade multiple times (at different times) and gotten the same error.

My WordPress site is hosted on Microsoft Azure, and I have never had problems upgrading a version of WordPress before. How do I make the upgrade correctly?

Comment: I would suggest temporary upgrade your instance size, so it doesn't timeout

Comment: The instance I have selected is the S1 Standard with 1 Core, and 1.75 GB RAM. Which instance should I upgrade to?

Comment: I tried to upgrade from S1 to S3 but it still timed out in the same way.

Comment: well, S1 should be fine, generally speaking, I guess you should consult wordpress logs

Comment: can you please check all things are correctly setup??

Comment: please prefer a manual upgrade instead of automatic

Comment: I'd prefer to do the automatic install through the panel, because the manual install has a lot of steps that I have never tried before: https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-manually-upgrade-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

Or is there an easier way to do the manual install?

Answer (score 0):

One of my updates seems to have gone through even though the WordPress admin said the updates failed. It now shows I have WordPress 4.7